# How much infrastructure damage has there been in Iraq, after the invasion?

Tags: united-states, war, iraq

I know that thousands up to a millions (depending on source) of people have died due to the conflict, but how much damage to infrastructure has been caused? I read somewhere that it was $1 trillion but it did not list what kind of buildings were damaged (hospitals, electricity, school etc...).

Comment: While we don't have a hard line distinction between current events and history, I'd argue that historical methods are of little value if the primary source documents are still being generated.

Comment: Which invasion?